# How to make a div fullscreen and atop of all other elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fullscreen

```
<div style="background-color:grey">
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: by fullscreen you mean full size of your browser window's viewport, right? as jQuery alone will not give you fullscreen capabilities... you'll need to use flash for that.

Answer (score 31):

Define a style `overlay` or something like so:

```
<style>
  .overlay {  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
  }
</style>
```

Then you can add the new class like this using jQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').addClass('overlay');
```

If you want to add with a click event you would do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#myDiv').addClass('overlay');
}
```

Or, you could add `display:none` to the .overlay class so it's hidden on page load, then have your jQuery `click` function show it like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('.overlay').show('slow');
}
```

Comment: How to put all those css parts into jQuery?

Comment: no need to put them; just define the class in your CSS file; and then in your Javascript,make this call "$('#myDiv').addClass('overlay');". It will automatically add all these attributes

Comment: You may want to make the overlay `position:fixed` so that it remains covering the whole viewport even when the user scrolls the page.

Answer (score 3):

**Full screen ajax loader, with some opacity.**

using

```
$('#mydiv').show(); 
$('#mydiv').hide();
```

to toggle it.

```
#mydiv {  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:grey;
    opacity: .8;
 }

.ajax-loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px; /* -1 * image width / 2 */
    margin-top: -32px;  /* -1 * image height / 2 */
    display: block;     
}

<div id="mydiv">
    <img src="lib/jQuery/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While doing so, you want to disable the user/input?

Check this: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Blocking elements: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Blocking whole page: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page

Rgds

Comment: I need simple lines to do this job.Not a plugin.

Comment: sure; then check jeerose's reply. However, it will not overlay the drop downs and activeX components such as flash or javaapplet.

Comment: +1 effkay - that's correct (re: activeX). @user198729 you do need a plugin for that unless you want to do LOTS of programming!

Comment: That's fine for me,because for the time being,there is no need to worry about activeX or flash.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```css
.overlay{ 
  background: #4caf5099; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed; 
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To make it fullscreen, set these styles:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

To put it on top, set the `z-index` value to something higher than the rest of the elements on the page.

```
z-index: 99;
```

You can set all these with a stylesheet, then just use jQuery to show/hide the div.